# Intent passed on startActivityResult() is null always

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera

In my app, I have to capture a photo from the native camera app and then store it in my desired folder and then show that captured image in a new Activity. My code so far

To start native camera

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

My other methods

```
private static Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type){
    return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
}

/**Create a file for saving an image*/
private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type){

    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "KidzPuzzle");

    //Create a storage directory if it does not exist
    if(! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
        if(! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
            Log.d("KidzPuzzle", "Failed to create directory");
            return null;
        }
    }

    //Create a media file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    File mediaFile = null;
    if(type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE){
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath()+File.separator+"IMG_"+timeStamp+".jpg" );
        return mediaFile;
    }else{
        return null;
    }
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    if(requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE){
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            //Image created and saved successfully to the specified fileUri
            //Toast.makeText(this, "Image saved to : \n"+data.getDataString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            String filePath = ((Uri) data.getExtras().get(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT)).toString();
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
            startActivity(new Intent(this, SplitImageActivity.class).putExtra("image", bitmap));
        }else if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
            //user canceled the captured image
        }else{
            //Image capture failed
        }
    }
}
```

The intent variable **data** in onActivityResult is always null. Please help me where I am going wrong.

NOTE:  When I debug it, the control always satisfies the RESULT_OK condition and the shows **NullPointerException**, because of the value of **data**.

And another thing, if I am not using

```
fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
```

this code before starting the native camera, then **data** is not null.

please help me.

Comment: if you pass extra data for taking picture it means: save image to XXX source path and if it is success return null. So if you get null it means everything is ok. This is standard result for iOS too.

Answer (score 0):

```
Chandra Sekhar,
```

as you have mentioned in the last that when you `don't specify location` for the image then `data is not null` so `AFAIK` it clearly indicates that when you pass location then it will return null and you will receive your image at your location. So you need to store that `location separately and use that to access image` when you get `RESULT_OK`.

Comment: is it the behaviour of android when we pass the location?

Comment: I am not sure whether it is the android behaviour or not and I too faced this.